# Shell Script for fetching data from DB into Excel

Tags: excel, shell, sqlplus

I have written shell script to fetch data from Database into Excel file, but it's not working as expected. Can any one please help.

```
enter code here

#!/bin/ksh
sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF 
CONNECT test/test@IP
alter session set nls_date_format= 'DD-MON-YYYY';
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM   (SELECT G2.USR_ID "User ID",G2.USR_NAME "User Name" ,
    G3.GFCT_NAME "Belong to Function", G2.USR_EMAIL "E-mail",G2.USR_SSOID "SSO ID" , 
    DECODE (G2.USR_INACTIVE+G2.NCR_INACTIVE,1,'Inactif',2,'Inactif',NULL,NULL) "NCR Inactif" 
  FROM GLOBAL_FUNCTION_ACTOR G1,GLOBAL_FUNCTION G3,USR_APPLI G2
  WHERE G1.USR_ID = G2.USR_ID AND G1.GFAR_ID  = '2' AND G3.GFCT_ID  =G1.GFCT_ID
  ) sub1
ORDER BY 3 ASC 
end;
/
EOF
```

Comment: This looks to be just an Oracle SQL query with nothing to do with Excel.

Comment: How do you expect that query to magically create an Excel file? The closest thing you can do with sqlplus is to export to a CSV file (and open that with Excel) - but that is quite cumbersome. You should rather look for a tool that can export proper Excel files directly.

Comment: That's where I need your help, i want that to be export in csv or Excel file. Or you can tell me what needs to be modified in script